# Different mirrored position when i need to join them

Tags: modeling

when I create head and body with different position, i want to join both of the head and the body. how to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the head ( uncheck clipping) and rotate it by 180 degrees on the z axis. Then you just have to move it until it is on the same side as the body. For the actual joining part select both edge loops, press F, then click the right mouse button and select bridge faces.